# "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error on VSCode Debug Console but 200OK code at network tab at Chrome DevTools

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

On an Angular 7 project, using HttpClient, I have this simple line of code on a click button handler:

```js
    this.http
      .get('http://localhost:30123/api/identity/name/' + this.name)
      .subscribe((answer: Identity[]) => {
        this.identities = answer;  // debug does not get here...
      });
```

that's throwing this error at the Console Debug tab on VSCode:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dihgldata.ingeniusds.cat/api/identitat/nom/montilla' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
[http://localhost:4200/] core.js:15724 {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://dihgldata.cat/api/identitat/nom…", ok: false, …}
```

but...

I'm using three different tools to test the same URL and getting a correct response from the api.

**First: Postman.**

(Well, you know: headers, CONTENT-TYPE,... are diferent when sent
from this utility than from chrome)

**Second: VS Code Extension Rest Client.**

(As per Postman, these utilities are useful to test the API but doesn't help with errors at the client side code)

**Third: Chrome DevTools.**

Here is my big deal. I went to Network tab on Chrome DevTools and I can see the response of the API just before it's been treated by my code and there is the full response with a OK-200 Status.

No errors at Console tab on Chrome DevTools.

Using VS Code integrated debugger with Chrome Extension tracing never gets to the line where the answer is assigned to the local variable and the error is shown in VSCode Debug Console with no other clue.

**EDIT**

Tried the same URL as on Angular HttpClient on Chrome address bar and the response from the same API is shown correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you doing request to http://localhost:30123/ from any another url it will be blocked by CORS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) politics of http://localhost:30123/.

You have to allow CORS from any url or from only http://localhost:4200/.

In Java you can use CORS Filter. https://howtodoinjava.com/servlets/java-cors-filter-example/

Comment: Hi Murrium, that's what I thought, but it's extremely strange for my because I can send a POST request from Chrome's address bar and I get the correct answer. But when the request is made from Angular code, the error is fired. Even more, on Chrome DevTools Network tab I can see the data sent by the API before it get's into Angular and Angular modules are not processing it.

Comment: When you use Chrome's address bar, you do request to localhost. For example, you have account on google and you now how to post data from it. Now you try to post it from yahoo, but CORS politics of google deny post requests from another domain. If you will try to do post request from postman to google, you will be blocked too via your domain, aka ip. So, when you do request to localhost, you have same domain, and hosts all ports, thats why it is not blocked by CORS. Angular localhost have access only to 4200 port, and your api to 30123, so thats why it CORS.

Comment: So you are saying CORS it's blocking at client level. Even when the API is processing the request, Angular is blocking the data?

Comment: No, its blocked by api, because Angular url is not allowed.

Comment: This is what I understood from CORS, but on Chrome DevTools Network tab I can see the data sent by the API, and before it get's into Angular, when I fire the request from my app!!

Comment: You have response that says 
_Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dihgldata.ingeniusds.cat/api/identitat/nom/montilla' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource._
Thats blocking only by api. It is business logic, not a wierd security hint

Comment: It seems it's been blocked by the client instead of the API!

Comment: Yes, I have that error message -in which I don't rely at all- but, what is getting me nuts is the data from the API request at the Network tab on Chrome DevTools.

Comment: Thats blocking only by api. It is business logic, not a wierd security hint.

Comment: Again, if blocked by the API, why can I see the request response full data at Chrome DevTools Network tab?

Comment: Do you have access to api? What it based on?

Comment: Sure. .net framework web.api v4.6. The request is processed by the API and the response sent back to the client. But Angular does not process it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192986/discussion-between-josep-alacid-and-murrium).

Comment: Actually, i dont know. I quess, browser controlls all the data, and blocks it.